# Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.android.tools/com.android.tools.MainActivity}

Tags: android

Want to create an application that generates the entire logcat for the device and stores them at specific location in device 
Created a system application in android build system and pushed the apk in device at "/system/app/test/test.apk"
Application is giving the Force close (Logs and Code are below)

#### Logs

```
01-01 14:51:59.002   859  1462 I ActivityManager: Start proc 4381:com.android.tools/1000 for activity com.android.tools/.MainActivity
01-01 14:51:59.003   859  1462 V BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : mPerf = com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@b30a5e0
01-01 14:51:59.016   426   618 D msm8916_platform: platform_set_channel_map mixer_ctl_name:Playback Channel Map12
01-01 14:51:59.017   426   618 D msm8916_platform: platform_set_channel_map: set mapping(1 2 3 0 0 0 0 0) for channel:2
01-01 14:51:59.017   426   618 D audio_hw_primary: start_output_stream: exit
01-01 14:51:59.089  4381  4381 I art     : Starting a blocking GC AddRemoveAppImageSpace
01-01 14:51:59.091  4381  4381 W System  : ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /system/app/test/lib/arm
01-01 14:51:59.173  4381  4381 W ResourceType: No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000000
01-01 14:51:59.174  4381  4381 D AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
--------- beginning of crash
01-01 14:51:59.176  4381  4381 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-01 14:51:59.176  4381  4381 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.android.tools, PID: 4381
01-01 14:51:59.176  4381  4381 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.android.tools/com.android.tools.MainActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
01-01 14:51:59.176  4381  4381 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2666)
01-01 14:51:59.176  4381  4381 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2727)
01-01 14:51:59.176  4381  4381 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
01-01 14:51:59.176  4381  4381 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1478)
01-01 14:51:59.176  4381  4381 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
01-01 14:51:59.176  4381  4381 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
01-01 14:51:59.176  4381  4381 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6121)
01-01 14:51:59.176  4381  4381 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
01-01 14:51:59.176  4381  4381 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:889)
01-01 14:51:59.176  4381  4381 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:779)
01-01 14:51:59.176  4381  4381 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
01-01 14:51:59.176  4381  4381 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.getValue(ResourcesImpl.java:190)
01-01 14:51:59.176  4381  4381 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1290)
01-01 14:51:59.176  4381  4381 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.createDrawableIfNeeded(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:234)
01-01 14:51:59.176  4381  4381 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:197)
01-01 14:51:59.176  4381  4381 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:188)
01-01 14:51:59.176  4381  4381 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.checkVectorDrawableSetup(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:723)
01-01 14:51:59.176  4381  4381 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:193)
01-01 14:51:59.176  4381  4381 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getDrawableIfKnown(TintTypedArray.java:81)
01-01 14:51:59.176  4381  4381 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:127)
01-01 14:51:59.176  4381  4381 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:147)
01-01 14:51:59.176  4381  4381 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV11.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV11.java:27)
01-01 14:51:59.176  4381  4381 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV14.java:53)
01-01 14:51:59.176  4381  4381 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV23.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV23.java:29)
01-01 14:51:59.176  4381  4381 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplN.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplN.java:29)
01-01 14:51:59.176  4381  4381 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:201)
01-01 14:51:59.176  4381  4381 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:185)
01-01 14:51:59.176  4381  4381 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:525)
01-01 14:51:59.176  4381  4381 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:74)
01-01 14:51:59.176  4381  4381 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.tools.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:18)
01-01 14:51:59.176  4381  4381 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6723)
01-01 14:51:59.176  4381  4381 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
01-01 14:51:59.176  4381  4381 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2619)
01-01 14:51:59.176  4381  4381 E AndroidRuntime:    ... 9 more
01-01 14:51:59.183   859   874 W ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.android.tools/.MainActivity
01-01 14:51:59.189   859   874 D ActivityTrigger: ActivityTrigger activityPauseTrigger 
01-01 14:51:59.225   859   891 V BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : mPerf = com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@f4b7c36
01-01 14:51:59.225   859   891 V BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : mPerf = com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@ac08737
01-01 14:51:59.231   859   891 V BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : mPerf = com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@a4b25c2
01-01 14:51:59.231   859   891 V BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : mPerf = com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@d8c5fd3
01-01 14:51:59.301   859  4399 I OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
01-01 14:51:59.301   859  4399 D OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
01-01 14:51:59.690   859   890 W ActivityManager: Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{75f27dc u0 com.android.tools/.MainActivity t45 f}
01-01 14:51:59.734   859   890 I WindowManager: Failed to capture screenshot of Token{1d130e5 ActivityRecord{75f27dc u0 com.android.tools/.MainActivity t45 f}} appWin=Window{dcdb7e3 u0 Starting com.android.tools} drawState=4
01-01 14:52:00.002  1219  1219 D KeyguardUpdateMonitor: received broadcast android.intent.action.TIME_TICK
01-01 14:52:00.003  1219  1219 D KeyguardUpdateMonitor: handleTimeUpdate
01-01 14:52:00.263  1908  2041 W OpenGLRenderer: Incorrectly called buildLayer on View: ShortcutAndWidgetContainer, destroying layer...
01-01 14:52:00.274   859   922 W WindowManager: Failed looking up window
01-01 14:52:00.274   859   922 W WindowManager: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Requested window android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@3799412 does not exist
01-01 14:52:00.274   859   922 W WindowManager:     at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.windowForClientLocked(WindowManagerService.java:9453)
01-01 14:52:00.274   859   922 W WindowManager:     at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.windowForClientLocked(WindowManagerService.java:9444)
01-01 14:52:00.274   859   922 W WindowManager:     at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindow(WindowManagerService.java:2398)
01-01 14:52:00.274   859   922 W WindowManager:     at com.android.server.wm.Session.remove(Session.java:202)
01-01 14:52:00.274   859   922 W WindowManager:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewRootImpl.java:3290)
01-01 14:52:00.274   859   922 W WindowManager:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doDie(ViewRootImpl.java:5923)
01-01 14:52:00.274   859   922 W WindowManager:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:3629)
01-01 14:52:00.274   859   922 W WindowManager:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
01-01 14:52:00.274   859   922 W WindowManager:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
01-01 14:52:00.274   859   922 W WindowManager:     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
01-01 14:52:00.274   859   922 W WindowManager:     at com.android.server.ServiceThread.run(ServiceThread.java:46)
01-01 14:52:01.264   859   874 I ActivityManager: Killing 4381:com.android.tools/1000 (adj 900): crash
```

#### MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Log.i ("Test","Started");
        if ( isExternalStorageWritable() ) {

            File appDirectory = new File( Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/MyPersonalAppFolder" );
           // File appDirectory1 = new File( Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "MyPersonalAppFolder.txt" );
            Log.i ("Test","Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()"+ Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());
            Log.i ("Test","Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()"+ Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath());

            File logDirectory = new File( appDirectory + "/log" );
            File logFile = new File( logDirectory, "logcat" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".txt" );
            Log.i ("Test","isExternalStorageWritable");
            // create app folder
            if ( !appDirectory.exists() ) {
                appDirectory.mkdirs(); // mkdir
                Log.i ("Test","appDirectory.exists"+ appDirectory.mkdirs());
            }

            // create log folder
            if ( !logDirectory.exists() ) {
                Log.i ("Test","Before_logDirectory.exists()" + logDirectory.exists());
                logDirectory.mkdirs();
                Log.i ("Test","logDirectory.mkdirs()"+ logDirectory.mkdirs());
                Log.i ("Test","After_logDirectory.exists()" + logDirectory.exists());
            }

            // clear the previous logcat and then write the new one to the file
            try {
                Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec( "logcat -c");
                process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec( "logcat -f " + logFile);
                Log.i ("Test","Logging started");
            } catch ( IOException e ) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } else if ( isExternalStorageReadable() ) {
            // only readable
            Log.i ("Test","readable");
        } else {
            // not accessible
            Log.i ("Test","not accessible");
        }
    }

    /* Checks if external storage is available for read and write */
    public boolean isExternalStorageWritable() {
        String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
        if ( Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals( state ) ) {
            Log.i ("Test","isExternalStorageWritable() : true");
            return true;
        }
        Log.i ("Test","isExternalStorageWritable() : False");
        return false;

    }

    /* Checks if external storage is available to at least read */
    public boolean isExternalStorageReadable() {
        String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
        if ( Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals( state ) ||
                Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals( state ) ) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

#### AndroiManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.android.tools"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0"
      android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

#### activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtEventType"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Looks like `windowBackground` attr is zero. It might come from your app theme.

Comment: Thanks, yes it was a theme issue.

Comment: Currently I am using the application in Userdebug build , is it possible to push the application in /system partition in user build